# Raspberry 3 dooes not boot any more after "sudo init 1"

Tags: raspbian, boot, pixel

Trying to change my root password I followed a hint that I just had to type `sudo init1` and then `passwd` and I would be able to change the root password.

But that was not right.

After typing `sudo init 1` and enter, the connection was cancelled and I was not able to rebuild it. The pi ran headless.

Now I connected a monitor and a keyboard. The Raspberry starts until the "Welcome to PIXEL" screen.

That's it. No more action.

Is there a possibility to undo whatever I changed?

Comment: Runlevel 1 should just put the Pi into single-user mode (which will kill the GUI and remote logins, login via terminal or serial would likely still work).  In any case, it shouldn't be permanent--just reboot and you should be back to normal.

Comment: You can't change the root password, because it doesn't have one. You CAN create one, but WHY?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change anything apart running `sudo init 1`? As BJ Black pointed out, that by itself should be pretty harmless.

Comment: Based on your comment that "the connection was canceled", I assume you were logged into the RPi remotely. `sudo init 1` will enter runlevel 1 which kills networking. That by itself shouldn't have done anything permanent, and a reboot should have solved the problem. Can you check logs or gather any other troubleshooting info? You didn't by any chance try appending a `1` to the end of `/boot/cmdline.txt` did you?

Comment: Based on the answer that was deleted, the OP said all he did was wait and the System prompted him to enter a new root password. That solved the problem for him. But his answer was unclear and now deleted.

Answer (score 1):

best way to create a root password is just type:

```
sudo -i
passwd
```

that'll give root a password without having to go into single user mode (init 1)

Comment: I believe the actual question is *how to undo the damage*, not *how to change the root password*.